# While working on react native app , I have mistakenly ran npm run android command on android directory, So , the whole gradle has been corrupted

Tags: android, react-native, build

This is what the error is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type ChecksumService using BuildSessionScopeServices.createChecksumService().
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\appv1\android\.gradle\8.0.1\checksums\checksums.lock (Access is denied)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not update D:appv1\android\.gradle\8.0.1\fileChanges\last-build.bin
> D:appv1\android\.gradle\8.0.1\fileChanges\last-build.bin (Access is denied)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I have tried:

```
./gradlew clean
```

but the same error showing and tried:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Even it doesn't start the installation. same error shows.

Comment: Can you revert your project to before this happened?

Comment: No , I tried But Some Build script for android is being corrupted as i ran "npm run android command from the android directory mistakenly . So  if any other possible commands could help me , suggest please .